# How to deploy keycloak to cloudfoundry

Tags: keycloak, cloud-foundry

As the title, is there any guide to deploy keycloak to cloud foundry?

Seems like cloudfoundry is only friendly to spring boot applications.

Comment: Cloud Foundry and Bosh are opensoure products. 
When there is a need, people create bosh releases and port a product onto cloud foundry. Here's a list of all available release - https://bosh.io/releases. Couldn't find one for `keycloak`. You can be the first to build a bosh release and port it onto cloud foundry

Comment: You can `cf push` most Java applications to Cloud Foundry via the standard Java build pack with very little work.  Just build a WAR file and push the WAR file.  The Java build pack will run installing OpenJDK & Apache Tomcat.  It will also configure Tomcat and deploy your WAR file.  If you have an application that cannot run in Tomcat (perhaps it needs a special Java application server, then you might need to use a different build pack).

Comment: `Seems like cloudfoundry is only friendly to spring boot applications.`  This is 100% false.  The standard Java build pack, while it has excellent support for Spring-based applications, can run a lot of different Java apps (see "Standard Containers" here https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/#additional-documentation for a list).  Plus any web app that can't be run with the Java build pack can almost certainly be run with some other build pack.

Comment: oops, I think I should try my first time to create a build pack staff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851758/keycloak-standalone-cluster-on-cloud-foundry/55934856#55934856

Answer (score 3):

### Keycloak Single Instance on CF

To deploy single instance try to `cf push` the [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) using `manifest.yml` like this (Postgres DB example):

```
---
applications:
- name: sso
  docker:
    image: jboss/keycloak
  instances: 1
  memory: 2G
  disk_quota: 2G
  env: 
    PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
    DB_VENDOR: postgres
    DB_ADDR: 192.168.1.23
    DB_PORT: 5432
    DB_DATABASE: keycloakdb
    DB_USER: keycloak
    DB_PASSWORD: a-lot-of-asterisks
```

You can do it also with the following commands without a manifest file:

```
$ cf push sso --docker-image jboss/keycloak -i 1 -m 2G -k 2G --no-start

$ cf set-env sso PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING true
$ cf set-env sso DB_VENDOR: postgres
$ cf set-env sso DB_ADDR 192.168.1.23 
$ cf set-env sso DB_PORT 5432 
$ cf set-env sso DB_DATABASE keycloakdb 
$ cf set-env sso DB_USER keycloak 
$ cf set-env sso DB_PASSWORD a-lot-of-asterisks

$ cf env sso
$ cf start sso

$ cf logs sso --recent
```

### Keycloak HA Cluster ona CF

Please look at: [Keycloak standalone cluster on Cloud Foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851758/keycloak-standalone-cluster-on-cloud-foundry/55934856#55934856)

### References

- https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/
- https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html
- https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/docker.html#public

---

Do you consider using [Cloud Foundry's UAA](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa)?

> CF UAA is the central identity management service for both users and applications, that supports: federated login, LDAP, SAML, SSO and multifactor authentication.

Comment: Tried Cloud Foundry's UAA in the first place, there are two things I didn't like there. 1. Single Sign Out seems is difficult to achieve; 2. Single Sign In is not available after UAA session timeout, users have to re-login after.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the easiest solution is to wrap Keycloak in a Spring-Boot application (together with the required JBoss parts) and deploy that. This allows you to create a single jar and push that to Cloud Foundry with the standard Java build pack.

This is exactly what someone has done [in this Github project](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-keycloak-server-example). The project injects a basic configuration for Keycloak with the default H2 database. All you need to do is clone the project, run `mvn package` and push the resulting jar to CF.