# Keycloak.X (quarkus based) on CloudFoundry

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, cloud-foundry

we want to deploy keycloak.X to cloudfoundry. I found older approaches ([How to deploy keycloak to cloudfoundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743371/how-to-deploy-keycloak-to-cloudfoundry)) with two options:

- wrapping it as a Spring application (see [1], but this project does not keep up with keycloak release cycle in time)
- using the docker image (`diego_docker`is disabled in my target environment)

So I am stuck with the Quarkus distribution.

Ideally, I dont want to change too much on the application itself (risk assessment ...) but only wrap it for cloud foundry.

The start script targets a class named `QuarkusEntryPoint`, but I don't know how to put it into a buildpack.

[1] https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server

Comment: Can you build it into a WAR file? You can deploy a WAR file using the Java buildpack. There is also a Liberty buildpack, if you need to deploy to a Jakarta EE server. It's very similar to the standard buildpack, but you get Liberty instead of Tomcat.

Comment: not sure. My curent try was to compile it into uber-jar (there is a quarkus option), but it did not work right away. I would also like to use prebuilt binaries for software compliance reasons :S